# Fatal error: This file has expired

Tags: php, zend-guard

I have a problem with my Zend Project. When I run it on localhost it says:

***Fatal error: This file has expired. in XX\XX\XX\XX\cake_project\Core\bootstrap.php on line 0***

My PHP version is 5.4, Apache version 2.2, and mySQL version 5.5, with Zend Guard Loader 3.3 and Ioncube loader too.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error. The code was encoded with Zend Guard but the license has expired. You'll need to get an updated license from wherever you bought the code.